# Slow Query on Table with 6M+ Records, even with Index

Tags: mysql

I recently migrated old records from a disturbingly designed table to a new table made and I need to filter records based on a given time frame - say that i need all from January 1, 2017, to December 31, 2017. The said table obviously has about 6M+ Records from 2014 up to the present.

A very basic query hilariously takes about 20~ seconds. I've also added an index on the column I'm referencing on the `WHERE` clause, but it seems that MySQL is not using it due to that. I need all columns present on the table (I could've made a composite index but I only need a few columns).

Below would be my query:

```
SELECT
    pt.* -- no index utilized at all @ 24.232s
    --  pt.out_date, pt.pt_id, pt.pi_id, pt.p_id, pt.out_status | makes use of cmpst_ndx_1 @ 9.380s
FROM
    process_trail pt
WHERE
    DATE(pt.out_date) BETWEEN DATE('2017-01-01') AND DATE('2017-12-31');
```

And here would be my table's definition:

```
Field           Type            Null        Key     Default     Extra
===============================================================================
pt_id           int(11)         NO          PRI                 auto_increment
pi_id           int(11)         NO          MUL     
p_id            int(11)         NO          
in_date         datetime        NO          MUL     
in_by_id        int(11)         NO          
out_date        datetime        NO          MUL     
out_by_id       int(11)         NO          
out_status      varchar(255)    NO          
out_remarks     text            NO          
tech_remarks    text            NO
```

Next are the indexes I've made:

```
Name        Fields      Index Type  Index Method    Collation   Cardinality
============================================================================
in_date     in_date     NORMAL      BTREE           A           3094370
out_date    out_date    NORMAL      BTREE           A           3001272
pi_id       pi_id       NORMAL      BTREE           A           302772
```

And the `EXPLAIN` syntax presents me this:

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows        filtered    Extra
==============================================================================================================================
1   SIMPLE      pt      (NULL)      ALL     (NULL)          (NULL)  (NULL)      (NULL)  3246351     100         Using where
```

Comment: How many rows are returned?

Comment: about 2M+ for 2017 records. i do have high doubts that this is one factor. given the time to populate millions of data, but stil...

Comment: dont ever use date(your_colum) stackoverflow.com/a/14104364/12582712

Answer (score 2):

My solution is

```
WHERE
    pt.out_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-12-31 23:59:59'
```

Because date function is may be slowing down

Comment: i have actually done that before my posting. it takes 21.726s for the data to show up. although it uses 2 index: out_date,cmpst_ndx_1. :(

Comment: I understand. You can try only get 1 field in select query. Or second way you can look mysql configuration.

Comment: on the my.ini file? which specific configuration should i modify.

Comment: You can use limit and offset also,but it depends on your requirement